# function is not a function, firebase function is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database

I have this issue, i try to do web with firebase. I use imported functions, but it keeps giving me error, that the function does not exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The word is: <span id="word"></span></h1>
    <h2>Top Players:</h2>
    <ul id="players-list"></ul>
    <script type="module">
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app.js";
      import {
        getDatabase,
        ref,
        orderByChild,
        get,
        query,
      } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-database.js";

      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      const firebaseConfig = {
        //config
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      function getWord() {
        return "car";
      }

      function getTopPlayers() {
        var db = getDatabase(app);
        var playersRef = ref(db, "players");
        var query = query(ref(db, "players"), orderByChild("starCount"));

        return get(query).then(function (snapshot) {
          var players = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var player = childSnapshot.val();
            player.key = childSnapshot.key;
            players.push(player);
          });
          return players.reverse().slice(0, 10); // Return top 10 players
        });
      }

      // Display the word returned by getWord() in the "word" span element
      document.getElementById("word").textContent = getWord();

      // Display the top players in the "players-list" ul element
      getTopPlayers()
        .then(function (players) {
          var playersList = document.getElementById("players-list");
          players.forEach(function (player) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = player.name + ": " + player.score;
            playersList.appendChild(li);
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

error is:
*Uncaught TypeError: query is not a function
at getTopPlayers (index.html:51:21)
at index.html:68:7*

Now it says, that query is not function.
Any ideas?

I tried it with ref and all of that stuff but still the same error.
tried everything, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var query = query(ref(db, "players"), orderByChild("starCount"));
> ```

`var query` creates a local (to the function) variable with an initial value of `undefined` (which is not a function) that [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `query` you are trying to access (which is a function).

Don't reuse variable names.

I recommend using ESLint with the [no-shadow rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) to catch this kind of error.